# NHibernate - Fetch referenced column value

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have this NHibernate model:

```
public class RootTable
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? Start { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? Finish { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Leaf1> ChildCollection1 { get; set; }
}

public class Leaf1
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Info1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Info2 { get; set; }
    public virtual RootTable Parent { get; set; }
}

public class RootMapping : ClassMap<RootTable>
{
    public RootMapping()
    {
        Table("RootTable");
        Id(c => c.Name);
        Map(c => c.Description, "Desc").Length(20);
        Map(c => c.Start).Length(20);
        Map(c => c.Finish).Length(20);
        HasMany(c => c.ChildCollection1)
            .Cascade.All()
            .LazyLoad()
            .Inverse();
    }
}

public class Leaf1Mapping : ClassMap<Leaf1>
{
    public Leaf1Mapping()
    {
        Table("LeafTable1");
        Id(c => c.ID, "RowID").GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(c => c.Info1).Length(20);
        Map(c => c.Info2).Length(20);
        References(c => c.Parent).Column("Parent").LazyLoad();
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is access the *value* of the referenced column in Leaf1 without lazyloading RootTable.

In otherwords, I have this:

```
this.LogMessage("Loading leaves...");
var allleafs = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Leaf1)).List<Leaf1>();
this.LogMessage("Loaded leaves...");
var leaf = allleafs[0];

this.LogMessage("Leaf metadata:");
// This causes a lazy-load of the RootTable object.
this.LogMessage("Leaf parent is " + leaf.Parent);
```

Now what I actually want is the *value* of "Parent" as it's stored in the underlying database - I don't care for the parent object, I don't want to load it, all I want to do get the raw value. I can't access the field that contains the value (i.e., `leaf.Parent.Name`) as I want this to work in a generic fashion...

**[Background]**
Ultimately this is plugging into an auditing framework that uses an NHibernate interceptor, so this needs to work in a generic way so that for any object passed in I can report on the changed values. It's entirely possible the child node will have changed with no change to the root node, so when the interceptor's `OnFlushDirty()` is called, I do *not* want the interceptor to cause a lazy-load of other objects.

I know I can reference the parent property directly (e.g., I can say "leaf.Parent.Name") and this will get me the value without the lazy load, but there doesn't seem to be a quick way to determine that "Name" is the key property I want to return.

**[Edited to add...]**
Walking the tree doesn't seem to work as I get a null reference exception:

```
var theType = leaf.Parent.GetType();

// This line returns a NULL due to the proxy class.
var metadata = factory.GetClassMetadata(theType);
var idProp = metadata.IdentifierPropertyName;

var prop = theType.GetProperty(idProp);
var val = prop.GetValue(leaf.Parent, null);

this.LogMessage("Leaf parent is " + val);
```

Now, theType comes back as `RootTableProxy`, so is just a placeholder because the main class isn't loaded. Which means `metadata` is null as there is no class metadata and thus `idProp` fails with a null reference exception.

So I can't actually see how to get referenced column value without a lazy load somewhere along the way: surely this can't be right?

**Edited to add (more!)**
I thought an easy solution have been found by using session.GetIdentifier(). However this doesn't seem to work in all cases: in an interceptor calling `session.GetIdentifier(state[i])` on some objects caused an exception stating that the object wasn't part of the current session, so still looking for a more reliable solution that doesn't resort to reflection. Any ideas welcome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about adding another property to your Leaf1 Class.

e.g.

```
public class Leaf1
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Info1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Info2 { get; set; }
    public virtual RootTable Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

and then map is as readonly

```
public class Leaf1Mapping : ClassMap<Leaf1>
{
    public Leaf1Mapping()
    {
        Table("LeafTable1");
        Id(c => c.ID, "RowID").GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(c => c.Info1).Length(20);
        Map(c => c.Info2).Length(20);
        References(c => c.Parent).Column("Parent").LazyLoad();
        Map(c => c.ParentId).Column("Parent").ReadOnly();
    }
}
```

Comment: This was a thought - we have a big domain model, so would need quite a large walk through the code to add this property. We might be able to limit it by only doing this on those properties that need it though - will take a closer look. Again seems a bit hacky though for something that I would have thought NH should give me for free... ah well.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your entities implement interfaces (would be cleaner), but if you want to get the actual type of the proxy, use NHibernateUtil.GetClass(proxy) which will return the underlying type that you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

It transpires that `ISession` has a method `GetIdentifier` which returns the cached value of a property. Taking the example from my original post, the code changes to this:

```
this.LogMessage("Loading leaves...");
var allleafs = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Leaf1)).List<Leaf1>();
this.LogMessage("Loaded leaves...");
var leaf = allleafs[0];

this.LogMessage("Leaf metadata:");
this.LogMessage("Leaf parent is " + session.GetIdentifier(leaf.Parent));
```

Now in testing this seems to be working nicely, and can be called from `OnFlushDirty` within an interceptor on both currentState and previousState objects.

I've been trying to find more information on `GetIdentifier`, but the NH documentation is sadly lacking, and there seems to be few, if any, blog posts that mention this. If anyone is aware of any caveats, problems, or "funnies" that I need to know aobut in relation to this method, I'd be more than happy to hear about them...

**[Edited to add]**
...as it turns out, this doesn't work if the object isn't a proxy object(!). Still looking for a reliable method to do this that doesn't involve reflection or decorating objects with attributes to identify fields.